# Closed form for integer moments of Poisson random variable?

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, poisson-distribution, hypergeometric-function, moment-generating-functions

I'm interested in a closed-form (special functions included) for the integer moments of the Poisson distribution.  Let $X\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$. Then we have for the moment generating function
$$
M_X(t)=\exp(\lambda(e^t-1))=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(\mathsf EX^k)\frac{t^k}{k!}.
$$
So if we can write the moment generating function as a Taylor series in $t$ we can extract the closed-form I'm looking for from the coefficients of said series. Write
$$
M_X(t)=e^{-\lambda}\exp(\lambda e^t)=e^{-\lambda}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\lambda^n e^{nt}}{n!}.
$$
Expanding the remining exponential and interchanging order of summation gives
$$
M_X(t)=e^{-\lambda}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{n^kt^k}{k!}
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(e^{-\lambda}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\lambda^n n^k}{n!}\right)\frac{t^k}{k!}.
$$
So we have
$$
\mathsf EX^k=e^{-\lambda}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\lambda^n n^k}{n!}.
$$
Can we write this series in terms of known special functions?  I'm pretty sure this can be written as a higher-order hypergeometric function (something like $_{k+1}F_{k}$) but not sure if there are other simpler closed-forms.

**Edit:**

We can write a hypergeometric form.  For $k=1,2,\dots$ the series evaluates to
$$
\mathsf EX^k=\lambda e^{-\lambda} {_{k-1}F_{k-1}}\left({2,\dots,2 \atop1,\dots,1};\lambda\right).
$$
But can this be reduced to simpler special functions?

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Higher_moments) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, @Kurt.G posted a link to the Wiki article on the Poisson distribution.  It turns out that for $X\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$
$$
\mathsf EX^k=T_n(\lambda)=B_n(\lambda,\dots,\lambda),
$$
where $T_n(x)$ is the $n$th Touchard Polynomial, which can also be written in terms of the the [complete Bell polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials) $B_n(x,\dots,x)$.

For a simple Mathematica implementation we have the one-liner

```
EXk[k_] := BellB[k, \[Lambda]]
```